# Does Iterator work only with numeric arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, iterator

I saw an example at w3schools:

```
<?php
// Create an Iterator
class MyIterator implements Iterator {
  private $items = [];
  private $pointer = 0;

  public function __construct($items) {
    // array_values() makes sure that the keys are numbers
    $this->items = array_values($items);
  }

  public function current() {
    return $this->items[$this->pointer];
  }

  public function key() {
    return $this->pointer;
  }

  public function next() {
    $this->pointer++;
  }

  public function rewind() {
    $this->pointer = 0;
  }

  public function valid() {
    // count() indicates how many items are in the list
    return $this->pointer < count($this->items);
  }
}

// A function that uses iterables
function printIterable(iterable $myIterable) {
  foreach($myIterable as $item) {
    echo $item;
  }
}

// Use the iterator as an iterable
$iterator = new MyIterator(["a", "b", "c"]);
printIterable($iterator);
?>
```

Can current method loop the arrays if it a associative array and not numeric.If yes how can i do it ? Example can we do something like this :

```
function printIterable(iterable $myIterable) {
  foreach($myIterable as $item => $value) {
    echo  "$item - $value";
  }
}

// Use the iterator as an iterable
$iterator = new MyIterator(["a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3]);
printIterable($iterator);
```

When i try it. It print this :   0 - 11 - 22 - 3

Comment: The output looks good to me, what did you want it to be? You might want to add a line separator after each line in printIterable() though, that way it'd be much easier to read :).

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo it is printing the array as numeric and it is associative can it be printet as associative just want to know

Comment: But that's because it *is* numeric. You make it that way in the constructor (array_values())

Comment: You can print associative arrays just like numeric ones. There's no difference between the two "types" in PHP in that regard.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo if i remove it. It shows this errors :
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\laragon\www\Testing\index.php on line 13
0 -
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\laragon\www\Testing\index.php on line 13
1 -
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\laragon\www\Testing\index.php on line 13
2 -

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo i know but with foreach you can print the key name too

Comment: That's because $this->pointer is initialized as 0, i.e numeric. Arrays in PHP have their own "internal" pointers (checkout next(), current() etc). Do you really need pointer?

Comment: No just wanted to know if i can print associative arrays with key=>value pairing using Iterables

Comment: Like I said before: "You can print associative arrays just like numeric ones." Using them in code might require some thought though, if the code expects one type or the other.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo i undestand but wanted to know if i can print like this name: Eric
email: Eric@gmail.com
age: 22 and i am confused on how to do it with the pointer

Comment: That's what I'm saying :). `$arr = ['name' => 'Eric']; foreach($arr as $k => $v) { echo "$k: $v\n"; }` Check https://www.php.net/next for starters and then the "See also" section on that page.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo if you look at the second block of my code i am doing that but it can not be printed because i am using a pointer to a associative array is there other way to use pointer.    If i dont put   array_values() function at contructor it doesnt print the array if i put it it prints the associative array as numeric. Maybe i am the most stupiest person on the planet and i am not understanding you :D

Comment: I'd leave that to the internal PHP array pointer, and then use the array functions I mentioned earlier.

Comment: "*If i dont put array_values() function at contructor it doesnt print the array if i put it it prints the associative array as numeric*"
Like I said before, if you add that array_values() call to the constructor *there is* no associative array. Array_values() returns a numeric "version" of the associative array which is then saved in $this->items.

Comment: "*it doesnt print the array*" I take it the code prints those messages about indexes? If you can't abandon $this->pointer I guess a workaround would be $this->keys and $this->items or $this->values. Then both could be numerical and $this->poijnter would work for both of them.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo yes i was using pointer wrong

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo can you show me an example with the way your are showing me to use  pointer cause i am new to php and can't get what you are saying here "If you can't abandon $this->pointer I guess a workaround would be $this->keys and $this->items or $this->values. Then both could be numerical and $this->poijnter would work for both of them"

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo i read what you wrote and i get it now i just didn't get your first version but it is because i have read about that functions i will read about them now thank you very much for your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP handles numeric and associative arrays the same way, there's no difference when printing them and the same code works for both(well, unless one starts adding fancy features..)

So yes, associative arrays can be printed.

The problem is that your code is assuming that the data array keys are numerical, by initializing the $pointer property to 0(that is, a numerical value). One can get around that either by using the internal pointer of the PHP array($this->items), or keeping an explicit list of the array keys.

**Version 1**
PHP has functions for traversing arrays, they're named next(), current(), key() etc and are listed under https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php. That way the array can be traversed without having an explicit pointer:

```
while(key($arr) !== null) {
  echo current($arr)."\n";
  next($arr);
}
```

If the methods specified under https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php are implemented in your class(`implements Iterator`) those functions can then be used, like this:

```
class MyIterator implements Iterator {
  private $items = [];
  private $pointer = 0;

  public function __construct($items) {
    $this->items = $items;
  }

  public function current() {
    return current($this->items);
  }

  public function key() {
    return key($this->items);
  }
  // ...
```

As can be seen it's more or less typing the same calls twice. But if you have a more complex Iterable and other pieces of code is added it might start being worth the work.

**Version 2**
If you don't want to rely on the functions from Version 1 you could still use $this->pointer, but you'll have to keep an explicit list of the array keys:

```
class MyIterator implements Iterator {
  private $items = [];
  private $keys = [];
  private $pointer = 0;

  public function __construct($items) {
    $this->items = array_values($items);
    $this->keys = array_keys($items);
  }

  public function current() {
    return $this->items[$this->keys[$this->pointer]];

    // Alternative version:
    return $this->items[$this->key()];
  }

  // Return the key of the current element
  public function key() {
    return $this->keys[$this->pointer];
  }

  // Step the array one element, and then return that value
  public function next() {
    // Check that we're not moving out of bounds, if so return null
    // and follow the next() spec.

    ++$this->pointer;
    return $this->items[$this->keys[$this->pointer]];
    
    // Alternative version:
    return $this->current();
  }
  // ...
```

As can be seen Version 2 creates another array "level" to keep track of(if associative and numeric arrays should both be supported). But it can be done.